# Find the range of the function $f(x)=\arccos (x^2 \cos 1 + \sin 1 \sqrt {1-x^4})$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse

Let $x^2=\cos a $

then the expression becomes
$$\arccos (\cos a \cos 1 + \sin a\ sin 1)$$
$$=a-1$$
$$=\arccos (x^2)-1$$

Which should mean range of the function is $[\pi -1, -1]$

Wolfram says it is $[0,1]$ (which is correct)

I get that there are probably some restrictions on $x$ and $\arccos x^2$, but i am not able to figure them out correctly. How should i proceed?

Comment: Note, the expression you wrote for the range has the form $[a,b]$ with $a\gt b$ instead of $a\lt b$. That in itself is a bit nonstandard. Also, the range of the arccosine function is usally taken to be $[0,\pi]$, so the range of $f$ should be some subset of $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: "Then the expression becomes...". I think there is a mistake. $1-x^4=(1-x^2)(1+x^2)$. In your substitution you forgot the term $1+x^2$ which is thus $1+cosa$. That "ruins" the sum formula you used

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

First of all, we need $x^2\le1$

As the principal value of $\arccos(y)\ge0$

$(1)\arccos(\cos(a-1))$ will be $\arccos(x^2)-1$

$\iff \arccos(x^2)\ge1\iff x^2\le\cos1$

$(2)\arccos(\cos(a-1))$ will be $1-\arccos(x^2)\iff x^2\ge\cos1$

Hope you can take it from here!

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with your attempt.

1. When doing variable substitution (especially trigonometric substitution), it's important to note the range of the new variable.  Since $\cos{a}=x^2 \ge0$ and $\sin{a}= \sqrt{1-x^4} \ge 0$, $a\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}].$
2. You cannot go from $p = \arccos(\cos(q))$ to $p = q$. The correct expression is $p = |q| + 2\pi n$ where $n$ is selected to put $p$ in $[0,\pi]$.

You established that
$$f = \arccos(\cos(a-1))$$
Which means that
$$f = |a-1| + 2\pi n$$

Since $a\in[0,\pi/2]$, it follows that
$$|a-1| \in [0,1]$$

And, since $[0,1]\subset[0,\pi]$, we don't need to worry about $n$ and the range of $f$ is $[0,1]$.

Comment: How is $|a-1|\in [0,1]$? $a\in (0,\pi/2)$ earlier, so how did it make the jump